# How to use Phonegap background thread in phonegap Android and IOS application

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am working in phonegap framework. I am using two type of thread function. first thread is call the API method get the message from web sever to insert sqlite database and another one thread is list data from Sqlite in UI that means my inbox page. the issue is hanging the device becaze the continues thread runing in the queue. so i want to use Android and ios background thread plugin. anybody know about the phonegap background thread plugin. Please help me.

this is the first thread function.

```
function itmerStart()
{
if (timerId) return
    var busy = false;
    timerId = setInterval(loadMessageListCron, 20000);

function loadMessageListCron()
{
$.ajax("http://mysamplesite.com/API/getallmessages?UserId="+ userid).done(function(data)
        {
          var i, response;
          $.each(data.messages, function (i, response)
            {
              inboxMessageItmerStop();
              insertMessages(response, i);
              inboxMessageItmerStart();
             });
         });
}
}
```

this is the second thread function.

```
function inboxMessageItmerStart()
{
if (timersId) return

    timersId = setInterval(loadInboxMessageList, 5000);
var busy = false;

function loadInboxMessageList()
{
    if(!busy)
    {
        busy = true;    
    var userid = window.localStorage.getItem("userId");
    if(userid != undefined)
    {
        db.transaction(queryDB,errorCB);       
    }
        busy =  false;
    }
}  
}
```